# How to make delimiter in python

Tags: python

Im making a python post script but it need to post email,password, it should delimited as `email|password` , any suggestion?

```
email = str(raw_input("Input Email List -> "))
list = open(email, "r")
mailist = list.readline().replace("\n","")
for line in mailist:
    line = line.strip('')
    email, password = line.split()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...but it need to post email,password,"*? Post what, where?

Comment: Don't use `list` ,it will give error

Comment: @Tojrah what do u mean by dont use list?

Comment: @Austin post to my crack tools api

Comment: list is reserved keyword in python for List data structures. It can't be used as variable name

Comment: so how do i make it delimited when im opening a file? @Tojrah

Comment: I have not understood exactly what you want. Perhaps you have email and password seperated by `|` and you want to split them. In that case use `.split('|')`

Comment: yes i have email separated by `|` , what i mean is , i want  to open the text file that in there are `email|password` @Tojrah